# Migrate bulk MS access MDB files data to oracle 11G

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ms-access-2007, data-migration

I have 500+ MS ACCESS MDB files, with huge data (400+ GBs) in total. I have a requirement to migrate it to oracle. All MDBs have same table structures.

Any suggestions for best approach will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is *best*, but - Oracle SQL Developer (a free GUI tool) offers **Migration Workbench** which lets you migrate MS Access into Oracle. Here are two pages you'd want to visit:

- *Migrating a Microsoft Access Database to Oracle Database 11g*: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/sqldev_migration/msaccess/migrate_microsoft_access_otn.htm
- *Migrating from Microsoft Access to Oracle*: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/access-084991.html

Comment: Thanks,I saw that option but don't think it will be helping me in case of bulk ms access files.